# Is it possible to run aframe inside electron?

Tags: electron, aframe

i've just started learning both electronjs (https://electronjs.org/) and aframe VR 3D (https://aframe.io/). But i'm not sure if aframe works inside electron? I cant find anything within google search. I get cross-origin policy error in the console then multiple three.js errors and a-scene.js errors. Ive have added the js file inside the html page:

```
<head>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script
</head>
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.

--- more info

im using https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start and then main.js consists of mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World!</title>
<script src="aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a-scene>

<a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>

<a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>

<a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>

<a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

<a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>

</a-scene>


</body>
</html>
```

aframe.min.js is now local but i still get the same errors

Comment: Can you please share the errors that you are facing? Also can you try to localize the aframe.js file instead of loading over internet?

Comment: Hi Nik, ive updated the text above and Ive basically done those steps.  Here is the screenshot of errors https://imgur.com/a/iupy1pf

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iupy1pf

Comment: I've just copy pasted your code to electron fiddle, and it worked out of the box. I loaded a-frame from the cdn and locally. Can you try it out with electron 4.0.3? Also could you share your specs for GPU/CPU if the error consists ?

Answer (score 0):

I use aframe with electron, it works fine for me.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/1.2.0/aframe.min.js" integrity="sha512-/gO16YMp20RIqCZXZyvMlzALQqEoiDU0akshw25wFiXCRGl+0p/HPWkOd8HWFn6bnatGhxakGLfYhWaPPVQIyA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

I got this script tag from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/aframe